# Right click to add icon into unity 2d panel not working

Tags: 12.04, unity, panel

I updated to 12.04 from 10.04, and had problems with sound. Now the sound works but I can't add icons to the top panel. I've tried all these and they don't have any effect:

- just right click
- alt + right click
- super + alt + right click
- hold left click + hold alt + right click

Comment: The Unity panel doesn't work like the Gnome2 panel. There aren't any settings you can change by clicking.  What do you want to do?

Comment: get to the panel settings to remove and add icons. for example I want to remove the battery icon, and switch user icon. so do i have to these through other settings

Answer (score 0):

You can't manually add items (e.g application launchers or widgets) to the Unity panel.

Comment: ok, but I can't open the panel settings anyway

Answer (score 0):

To remove the battery icon you can either remove the package `indicator-power`, run `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.power icon-policy 'never'` in a Terminal or use [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings) and set "Panel" -> "Show battery status" to "Never".

You can't change the user menu icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unity-tweak-tool for some tweaking (Removing the battery or bluetooth indicators, for instance), but you can not add new launchers or indicators, I'm afraid...